# installing composer on centos

Tags: php, laravel, centos, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer on my server (centos) but I keep getting this error : 
The phar extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar
ps:I am trying to install composer to work with laravel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [--enable-phar=shared Do I have to recompile PHP to Install Composer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971607/enable-phar-shared-do-i-have-to-recompile-php-to-install-composer)

Answer (score 3):

**Specifically for CentOS**

Edit the file `/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini` and remove the `;` character in front of the line:

```
extension=phar.so
```

Now the phar extension is enabled.

Comment: Which version of CentOS? It's not there on CentOS 6.9, and the information in PHP clearly states it not even compiled ('--disable-phar')

Answer (score 1):

Composer is provided as a phar as that extension is [a standard part of PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.installation.php) which is also the minimum required version for running Composer at all.

If you have a weird version of PHP 5.3+ without the phar extension you could also convert it to a zipball or tarball via [online tools](http://unphar.com/), unpack it to `/usr/local/share/composer`, and then symlink manually from `/usr/local/bin/composer` to `/usr/local/share/composer/bin/composer`. Assuming no other settings are preventing installation that should work as well.

Comment: how can I install the phar extension (my server is centos by the way)

Answer (score 0):

PHAR is part of the PHP core since some years now. Its already installed as dynamic/shared extension, but probably and simply not activated in your case

Please check your php extension folder for a file "phar.so".

To enable the extension:

1. Go to your `php.ini` and enable `extension = phar.so`
2. Check the loaded PHP Extensions with `php -m` and look for "Phar"
3. Then re-run the Composer install

Answer (score -3):

First, you need to get composer.phar by doing :

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

And move the composer.phar for using globally :

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: I keep getting the same error : The phar extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar

Comment: Do you have php installed on your server ? You can try "php -v" to check this. If php is not recognized, you can install it by doing "sudo apt-get install php5".

Comment: the php version is : 5.3.28

Comment: PHP needs an extension to allow using .phar files. It is useless to ignore the warning by simply rerunning the installation instructions.